# gfx.js on Torch / Lua, how to visualize an image?

Tags: lua, torch, gfx

I would like to use gfx.js in my Torch / Lua code, but it does not seem to work.
I tried to install it and to run it by following [the instructions here](https://github.com/clementfarabet/gfx.js/).

The installation worked fine. Then I ran:

```
$ luajit -lgfx.start
$ th
> gfx = require 'gfx.js'
> gfx.image(image.lena())
```

But then no image is shown. Instead, this string is printed:

```
[gfx.js] rendering cell <dom_1442598176079420629243124>
```

I've no idea about what this means and why I got it. 
Can someone give me some suggestions?

I'm working on CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core).

Comment: Do you have your browser running and connected to the `gfx.js` server?

Comment: Ouch... you'right, I was expectin' to see the image as a new window while it was loaded in my browser... quite embarassin ' ^_^ If you want to write down the answer, I'll accept it and we can close this stupid question of mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the documentation reads it sounds like the `gfx.image` call will create the new image window in the browser accessed "page" that the first call started the server for.

That message looks very much like a "success" status message about `gfx.js` having done that.

Do you have that page loaded in your browser when you try this?